# dereference triple pointer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dereference

```
struct integer3_1 {
    int value3;
};

typedef struct integer3_1* intPtr;

struct integer3{
    intPtr* vPtr;
};

typedef struct integer3* intpointer3;   

int main() {
    int value = 5;
    intpointer3 intPtr3 = (intpointer3)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
    //(*intPtr3->vPtr)->value3 = value;
    //(*(*intPtr3).vPtr)->value3 = value;
    //(*intPtr3->vPtr)->value3 = &value;
    //(*(*intPtr3).vPtr)->value3 = &value;

return;

}
```

Hi, I have a question

how can I dereference the intPtr3 to be able to store the value of 5 into the `intPtr3->vPtr->value3`

I tried a few ways, but I kept getting error @@a

---

2nd part

```
//1st line
intpointer3 intPtr3 = (intpointer3)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
//2nd line
(*intPtr3).vPtr = (intPtr*)malloc(sizeof(intPtr));
//3rd line
*((*intPtr3).vPtr) = (intPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3_1));
```

1) At the 1st line, it allocate a storage for intpointer3?

2) At the 2nd line, you dereference and allocate a storage for intPtr?

3) At the 3rd line, what have you dereference? what storage have you allocate?

4) What is the difference between

```
(intpointer3)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
```

and

```
malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
```

?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not dereference. You didn't allocate memory for `integer3_1` yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure `integer3` is defined as

```
struct integer3{
    intPtr* vPtr;
};
```

Then the solution would be as shown below

```
intpointer3 intPtr3 = (intpointer3)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
```

`intPtr3` is of type `intPointer3` which is same as `integer3 *`. Hence, first we need to allocate space for an object of size `integer3`.

```
(*intPtr3).vPtr = (intPtr *)malloc(sizeof(intPtr));
```

`*intPtr3` will give an object of type `integer3`. `integer3` has a pointer `vPtr` of type `intPtr*`. Hence, we need to allocate space for an object of size `intPtr` and assign it to `vPtr` and hence, this statement.

```
*((*intPtr3).vPtr) = (intPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3_1));
```

`(*intPtr3).vPtr` will give an object of type `intPtr *` which is same as `integer3_1 **`. Hence, this statement `*((*intPtr3).vPtr)` will dereference to `*(integer3_1 **)` which is same as `integer3_1 *`. Hence, we need to allocate space for an object of size `struct integer3_1` and assign it to this pointer.

```
(*((*intPtr3).vPtr))->value3 = value;
```

The LHS of `->` operator is a pointer of `integer3_1 *` type and hence, to access `value3` and hence, the need for `->` operator.

```
printf("Value is %d\n", (*((*intPtr3).vPtr))->value3);
```

Last question:

```
(intpointer3)malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
```

and

```
malloc(sizeof(struct integer3));
```

are same except that we are explicitly type-casting the allocated pointer to `intpointer3` or rather `integer3 *` in the first case. This is required while developing in a `C++` environment like `MSVC++`. This is not necessary while developing with `gcc`.

Comment: @RexRau.. Are you facing any `compilation` issues or `runtime` issues? I tried this on `gcc` and it is working at my end.

Comment: ggc is complier? I am using visual stdio 2012, I think the code not work on visual stdio?

Comment: @RexRau .. Yes `gcc` is a compiler. I have tried the same code on `Visual C++ 2010 Express` just now and it is working fine. I have copy-pasted my code in `cfiddle` as in the `link` above. Can you check with the attached code and confirm?

Comment: I checked it, and your set up is different than mine, in my the structure of integer3, it has intPtr* vPtr; but your structure only has intPtr vPtr

Comment: @RexRau.. I had copied your code directly and pretty sure didn't modify it. In any case.. I have modified my answer to handle the current definition of `integer3` structure. Now I feel it should work.

Comment: I tried it, and it is work :D thank you. And I have a few questions, I put in my post above.